# Show $ \lim_{t \to \infty} -t^{x}e^{-t} = 0 $

Tags: limits

I have this limit (derived from an improper integral in the larger problem) that WolframAlpha says equals zero. But it doesn't have the steps to get there. How indeed do I show this instead of waving my hands that we can apply l'Hospital's rule to infinity and the denominator will eventually win and the limit will approach zero.

Check form ($\infty * 0$):
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} -t^{x}e^{-t}$$
Rearrange into $\frac\infty\infty$:
$$= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{-t^x}{e^t}$$
Apply l'Hospital's Rule:
$$= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{-xt^{x-1}}{e^t}$$
I don't see a clear way of showing this goes to zero, but zero is the correct answer.

Comment: $x$ is a constant, correct?

Comment: You didn't apply L'H correctly...

Comment: @Mark, yes, the parent integral is with respect to u.

Comment: It is $-t^x=-e^{\ln(t)x}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, it's been 3 years since I've used calculus, what did I do wrong?

Comment: [This](https://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/exppoly.pdf) pdf may also be useful.

Comment: $\frac d{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}\ne\frac1nx^{n-1}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt ah yes, a simple mistake. Also thanks for directing me to the duplicate -- your answer there helps; thanks.

Comment: If the dupe answers your question, you should click the "Yes, that answers my question" button.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try and use l'hopital $x$ times, and then show:

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^t}=0 \implies \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t}{e^t}=0 \implies \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^2}{e^t}=0 ... $$

Because differentiating $t^x$ leads to $t^{x-1}$ multiplied by a constant (and constants don't matter in limits).